# Ansible playbook to install different packages depending on os version

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook (using ansible 1.9.3) that sets up and updates a bunch of servers. One of those steps is to install packages (using the 'apt' plugin). Until recently all of my servers have been uniform (same version of Ubuntu server). I'm introducing a newer Ubuntu server and some of the package names have changed.

Here's what my tasks file looks like:

```
- name: install needed packages
  apt: name={{ packages }} state=present update_cache=yes
```

(and I have a list of packages in a vars file).

I could define a variable in my inventory file for the hosts with a different Ubuntu version.

How do I change this task to use one list of packages for my current hosts, and another list of packages for my newer hosts?

Comment: "*Here's what my tasks file looks like*"... and it doesn't work, because using bare variables in with-clauses has been deprecated for over 2 years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `when` clause. Here's an example that will only run on ubuntu 12.04

```
when: "'{{ ansible_distribution}}' == 'Ubuntu' and '{{ ansible_distribution_release }}' == 'precise'"
```

You could alternatively use:

```
when: "'{{ ansible_distribution }}' == 'Ubuntu' and '{{ ansible_distribution_version }}': '12.04'"
```

**Edit:**
Later versions of Ansible (e.g. 2.7.1) would print a warning for this statement:

> [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: '{{ansible_distribution}}' == 'Ubuntu' and '{{ ansible_distribution_release }}' == 'bionic'

Ansible now expects another syntax for conditional statements, as stated in the docs.

For [Ansible 2.5](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) you could try this:

```
when: "ansible_distribution|string == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_release|string == 'bionic'"
```

or even:

```
when: 
  - ansible_distribution|string == 'Ubuntu'
  - ansible_distribution_release|string == 'bionic'
```

The [latest version of the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) suggests to use access the ansible_facts like this:

```
when:
  - ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS"
  - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "6"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Would you repeat the same task twice but with a different `when`?

Comment: That should work. You should test the output of the variables with something like this: `ansible all -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution*"`

Comment: I get this error: `error while evaluating conditional: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_release == 'trusty'`. Do I need to install a plugin or something first?

Comment: No plugins necessary. Unfortunately, it's not a very useful error. It could be mismatched quotes, but it could be other things as well.

Comment: See if my edited answer example gives better results.

Answer (score 9):

To keep your playbooks cleaner, you could do this within the roles, for example, you could  have a single `tasks/main.yml` the one based on the OS it will include the tasks matching the condition used with `when`, for example, if using `ansible_os_family` the contents of `main.yml` could be something like:

```
---
- include_tasks: freebsd.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == "FreeBSD"
  tags:
    - unbound

- include_tasks: debian.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
  tags:
    - unbound

- include_tasks: redhat.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
  tags:
    - unbound
```

The advantage of this approach is that besides only having a set of task per OS, you can also tag the full tasks.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done even simpler and more generic allowing re-use of the same task for multiple distributions or os:es

Simply storing the packages per distribution in a dictionary

vars file:

```yaml
packages: {
           bionic: [ bionic-package1, bionic-package2],
           focal: [focal-package1, focal-package2]
          }
```

playbook:

```yaml
- name: Install unique packages per distro
  package: 
    name: "{{ packages[ansible_distribution_release] }}"
    state: present
```

Note that the change to "package" module from "apt" which allows task to run on any Linux distributions not only ones using apt as a package manager